# Can i used stock images in a portfolio for university?

Tags: portfolio, stock-images, art

I want to get in to a graphic design course in university. I have alot of projects in mind, however i dont know if im allowed to use stock photos...would it be ok if they were in the final piece as well (such as in a magazine cover or a brochure). I also want to do photomanipulation, but i dont know if could use stock photos for that either.
Thankyou so much

Comment: What do the terms of the stock photos say? Generally, when you buy a stock photo, you’re buying a licence to use that photo in specific circumstances – only the licence can tell you whether your intended use is covered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to include in my portfolio?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69159/what-to-include-in-my-portfolio) or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104452/is-it-ok-to-use-watermarked-photos-in-my-project-which-will-be-in-my-portfolio or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/using-stock-images-for-mock-ups

Comment: ill be using free stock images, the ones that r copywrite free from websites like pexel im just not sure if the unis will be ok with it or if i have to use my own photos (that would be a problem)

Comment: There's no such thing as "copyright free" other than 75+ year old "Public Domain" images. They **all** come with terms and rarely if ever are they entirely rights free. Check Terms of Service and Licenses.

Comment: oh i mean u know those website that where people add photos they took for people to download for free, so long as you give them credit for it, its those ones. sorry i thought it was called copywrite free, i'll definately do my research on licensing and stuff

Comment: Ask your teachers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock images are typically how things are done. It not possible to travel to, or set up a custom photo shoot for every image necessary.

it's fine to use stock image in a portfolio. Be sure you purchase the images though... *don't* merely use Google as your image source. If asked, merely state "It's a stock image." There's no shame or harm in that.

---

Photo manipulation is generally okay with stock images as well. I mean I *never* use a straight image as it was purchased. I always do *something* to to it.

Just be careful with the license where photo manipulation is concerned... i.e. a stock image manipulated and then sold as a poster *may* be beyond any licensing terms.

> Example... 
> I recently discovered a sticker being sold on Amazon that uses a stock illustration I created. I **know** for a fact resell rights weren't granted. So.. yeah.. there's a legal issue where someone is infringing upon my rights by selling a sticker.

But merely for a portfolio, to show off skills, you'd be fine.

Comment: thankyou so much! I was pretty stressed out about this but i guess it was nothing to worry about, and yes i will definately alter the photos in some way shape or form